# How to add anchor in Wicket's setResponsePage()?

Tags: redirect, wicket, anchor

We need to redirect users that access a certain url to a Wicket page and scroll to a anchor in the page. E.g., the users link directly to `http://.../target/url/123`. Afterwards, the `123` id is looked up from database. Subsequently, the user will be redirected to a different page based on if the entity was found or not.

After the entity has been fetched the user should be redirected to `http://.../another/url/123#element123`. How can we achieve this with Wicket? The page should also be accessible without the anchor, and preferably, the solution should be generic.

One solution I came up with is to override the `PageParametersEncoder` logic to append `#anchor` to url when the `PageParameters` contains an entry named `anchor`. However, this means that I also need to extend the `Url` class with my own to append the anchor.

```
public class ExtendedEncoder extends PageParametersEncoder {

    public static final String ANCHOR = "anchor";

    @Override
    public Url encodePageParameters(PageParameters pageParameters) {
        Url fromSuper = super.encodePageParameters(pageParameters.remove(ANCHOR));
        return new ExtendedUrl(fromSuper,
                pageParameters.get(ANCHOR).toOptionalString());

    }
}

public class ExtendedUrl extends Url {
        private String anchor;

        private ExtendedUrl(Url url, String anchor) {
            super(url);
            this.anchor = anchor;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(StringMode mode, Charset charset) {
            return super.toString(mode, charset)
                   + anchor == null ? "" : "#" + anchor;
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any other solutions for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code renders a javascript snippet into the html of your target page that upon page load will focus the page on the anchor specified in the url.

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    long anchor = getRequest().getQueryParameters().getParameterValue("anchor").toLong(0);
    if (anchor > 0) {
        response.render(new OnLoadHeaderItem("location.href='#anchor" + anchor + "';"));
        anchor = 0;
    }
}
```

btw, this is for wicket 6. You can do similar stuff though in 1.5 and previous versions.

Comment: Yeah, that would do the trick. However, it would make the `anchor` parameter visible in the url like `/page/123?anchor=foo#foo`. Furthermore, you would need to add the code to each page, so it is not very generic.

Comment: @rjokelai I always have a base page from which I subclass all the pages of my application, so it has never been a problem for me. I used this pattern with content pages where the anchor parameter was a comment id and making it visible in the url was not a problem. But if you are looking for a render time only solution, then your only option is wicket6 and your solution of using a custom PageParameterEncoder that adds an addition # character and moves your anchor tag to the end of the parameter list. I think opening a ticket with a feature request on apache.issues.org would be a good idea.

Comment: I think the `PageParametersEncoder` can be overridden also in Wicket 1.5, since it is passed as a parameter to the `MountedMapper`. I think we'll go with the javascript solution even though it makes the urls a little bit uglier :)

Answer (score 0):

you could ask for the URL of the page and then redirect

```
String fullUrl = RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer()
    .renderFullUrl(Url.parse((String) urlFor(RedirectPage.class,parameters)));
setResponsePage(new RedirectPage(fullUrl+"#anchor"));
```

Comment: Nice, but Wicket complains: `Unable to create page from class org.apache.wicket.markup.html.pages.RedirectPage. Class does not have a visible default contructor.`. I think this is because it tries to instantiate the `RedirectPage` with `RedirectPage(PageParameters)` constructor, which does not exist.

Comment: Also, the `fullUrl` seems to contain `http://localhost:8080/...`. Will it actually work in real environment?

Comment: maybe different wicket version i am running 1.5

Comment: We are using Wicket 1.5, too.