# Wicket: tell the browser to scroll to certain tag (anchor)

Tags: wicket

We are using Wicket and our generated pages are quiet long (a lot of vertical scrolling). Some links or form's `onSubmit` methods invoke just perform some actions on the database and show the same page again:

```
public class MyPage extends WebPage {

    public MyPage(PageParameters parameters) {
        ....

        final Form<Void> form = new StatelessForm<Void>("formId") {
            protected void onSubmit() {
                // some database stuff
                ...
                setResponsePage(getClass(), getPageParameters());
            }
        };
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I make the `setResponsePage` invocation cause the browser scroll to the form, so the page is not just showing the top? Maybe some JavaScript-injection?

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14436899/461499

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a nice Wicket-y solution combines stuff that is already in Michael's answer, with a `Behavior`, so you can just `add` this to your form.

```
form.add( new ScrollToTopBehavior());
```

The behaviour itself would like something like this:

```
public class ScrollToTopBehavior extends Behavior
{

    @Override
    public void renderHead( Component component, IHeaderResponse response )
    {
        super.renderHead( component, response );
        response.render( JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference( Application.get().getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().getJQueryReference() ) );

        component.setOutputMarkupId( true );

        String script = String.format("doSomeJavaScriptStuff('%s')", component.getMarkupId());
        response.render( OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript( script ) );
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

For scrolling to a specific ID / ANCHOR only once, you can follow this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3163635/461499

Comment: Yes, it will add more elegance to my answer :)

Comment: When to set this ScrollToTopBehavior? In the `onSubmit`-method?

Comment: @Thomas, no, currently after `form` creation in your code (or creation of any other component you want this behavior applies to).

Comment: But it only should scroll there after having clicked the Submit button.

Comment: @Thomas, and it will. You should read [more](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/advanced.html#advanced_1) about wicket behaviors

Comment: It will scroll there every time the form is rendered. If you want more logic, you can add this logic to the behavior, for example with a setEnabled() method that is called from the form.onSubmit()

Answer (score 2):

**JS of course**.

This would be something like (with JQuery usage):

```javascript
var scrollPosition = $('#scrollToMarkupId').offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: " + scrollPosition + " }, 'slow');
```

where `scrollToMarkupId` is wicket component's markup id, which could be obtained by calling `component.getMarkupId()` method.

*I'm not pro in JS, so you can try to google better impl may be.*

---

**Now, about wicket:**

1) As for me, I prefer AJAX invocations for such behavior ( note that if you use such approach your page won't be stateless ):

```java
// do not override your form's `onSubmit()` method
final Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("formId");
// adding ajax behavior with `onSubmit()` method overriding.
form.add ( new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior ("submit")
{
    protected void onSubmit ( AjaxRequestTarget target )
    {
        // your submit logic
        // then insert js, descriped above:
        target.appendJavaScript ("..." + componentToScroll.getMarkupId() + "..");
    }
});
```

This approach won't reload your page at all but also post your data.

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

2) You also could execute JS after page loading, by overriding `renderHead` method:

```java
public class YourPage extends WebPage
{
...
    @Override
    public void renderHead ( final IHeaderResponse response )
    {
        //replace `...` by your script.
        response.render ( OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript ( "..." );
    }
...
}
```

Such script will be invoked after page is renedered (and `setResponsePage` method will render your page). You can use this approach for any components and panels too.

Answer (score 0):

I've now use following JavaScript injecting code:

```
add(new Behavior() {
    @Override
    public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(component, response);

        response.render(new HeaderItem() {
            @Override
            public Iterable<?> getRenderTokens() {
                return Collections.singletonList("javascript-anchor");
            }

            @Override
            public void render(Response response) {
                response.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n");
                response.write("window.location.href='#rules';\n");
                response.write("</script>\n");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Feel free to comment (I'm a complete JS-noob with only very limited experience in Wicket).

Comment: Hi Thomas, this look ok. I would try to remove the hard-coded #rules, but as you use this behavior as anonymous subclass I think it is ok.

Comment: Also, you can use Wicket to wrap the javascript: `response.write(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forScript("win......"));`