# Wicket: scroll to certain anchor after clicking a link

Tags: java, wicket

I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354911) for a form, but now need to scroll to an anchor after the user clicked a certain link - [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354911#answer-27360098) from the other thread does not work. :(

```
final Link link = new StatelessLink("linkId") {
  @Overrride
  public void onClick() {
    doSomething();

    add(new Behavior() {
       @Override
       public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
         super.renderHead(component, response);

         response.render(new HeaderItem() {
           @Override
           public Iterable<?> getRenderTokens() {
             return Collections.singletonList("javascript-anchor");
           }

           @Override
           public void render(Response response) {
             response.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n");
             response.write("window.location.href='#rules';\n");
             response.write("</script>\n");
           }
         });
       }
     });
     setResponsePage(getClass(), getPageParameters());
  }
}
```

What's wrong with this approach and how to achieve the desired scrolling-to-anchor effect?

Comment: `element.scrollIntoView()`?

Comment: I think, the core problem seems rather that my JavaScript is not part of the rendered page - instead of when using a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using following non-JavaScript code instead:

```
final Link link = new StatelessLink("linkId") {
  @Overrride
  public void onClick() {
    doSomething();

    final String url = RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(Url.parse(urlFor(getClass(), getPageParameters()))) + "#rules;
    setResponsePage(new RedirectPage(url));
  }
}
```